# Parsing XML to get all elem.tag: elem.text pairs

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing [ICD-10 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10) and have achieved a result that satisfies my base case, but I'm worried about how fragile my method is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# A sample of the larger XML file I'm parsing
data = '''<diag>
<name>A00</name>
<desc>Cholera</desc>
<diag>
  <name>A00.0</name>
  <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
  <inclusionTerm>
    <note>Classical cholera</note>
  </inclusionTerm>
</diag>
<diag>
  <name>A00.1</name>
  <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</desc>
  <inclusionTerm>
    <note>Cholera eltor</note>
  </inclusionTerm>
</diag>
<diag>
  <name>A00.9</name>
  <desc>Cholera, unspecified</desc>
</diag>
</diag>'''

# Create the tree
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))

# the `iter` method returns all tags in a given tree
# I'm just grouping the tags and texts here
def get_all_elements(tree):
    return [(elem.tag, elem.text) for elem in tree.iter()]

# This will return the desired elements from my tree
def parse_elements(tree):

    # First, get all of the elements in the tree
    elements = get_all_elements(tree)

    to_return = {}

    # This is what I think is too fragile. I'm basically looking
    # ahead for each element to see whether the next two elements
    # match the diag -> name -> desc sequence. But this indexing seems
    # to be too fragile at scale.
    for idx, elem in enumerate(elements):
        if 'diag' in elem and 'name' in elements[idx+1] and 'desc' in elements[idx+2]:
            name = elements[idx+1]
            desc = elements[idx+2]
            to_return[name[1]] = desc[1]
    return to_return

res = parse_elements(tree)
```

Let's see what's in `res`:

```
for k,v in res.items():
    print("name (code): ", k, "\n  desc: ", v)

name (code):  A00.9 
  desc:  Cholera, unspecified
name (code):  A00.0 
  desc:  Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae
name (code):  A00 
  desc:  Cholera
name (code):  A00.1 
  desc:  Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor
```

So, I achieve my desired output, but I keep thinking there much be a better way to parse this XML. Unfortunately there's no `<diag><subdiag></subdiag></diag>`-type of hierarchy. Even subdiagnoses are labeled with the `<diag>` tag. I suppose the above is my attempt at recursion -- although I have found true recursion tough with the current tag-naming. At the end of the day, I just need the `name: desc` pairs.

Edit:

There's also this approach:

```
names = [x.text for x in ET.fromstring(data).findall('.//name')]
descs = [x.text for x in ET.fromstring(data).findall('.//desc')]

res = zip(names, descs)
```

But I don't think this approach scales well, as the number of elements in `names` and `descs` differed by about 1000 when I tested this on the larger XML file. There were mismatches between codes and descriptions when I validated on actual codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the latter approach resulted into broken mismatched pairs, looks like there are codes with no descriptions.

If you want to capture only the diagnosis codes that have descriptions (existing `desc` nodes), you can enforce this rule with the following XPath expression:

```
.//diag[name and desc]
```

The problem though is that `xml.etree.ElementTree` [supports a limited set of XPath features](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) and for this particular expression to work, you need to switch to [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/index.html). But, it will come with a performance boost, better memory usage and a richer functionality. It's worth it.

You can also simplify the way you extract codes by using `findtext()` and a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
from pprint import pprint

import lxml.etree as ET


data = """your XML here"""
root = ET.fromstring(data)

result = {diag.findtext("name"): diag.findtext("desc")
          for diag in root.xpath(".//diag[name and desc]")}

pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

XPath support fetching parent element https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax. Let's try to find `name` element and get parent of this element:

```
>>> [x for x in tree.findall('.//name/..')]
[<Element 'diag' at 0x7f9c8cece278>,
 <Element 'diag' at 0x7f9c85a84908>,
 <Element 'diag' at 0x7f9c85a93f98>,
 <Element 'diag' at 0x7f9c85a8f188>]
```

When we have parent element, we can get `name` and `desc` elements:

```
>>> [(x.find('name'), x.find('desc')) for x in tree.findall('.//name/..')]
[(<Element 'name' at 0x7f9c875ba7c8>, <Element 'desc' at 0x7f9c8cedfe58>),
 (<Element 'name' at 0x7f9c85a84958>, <Element 'desc' at 0x7f9c85a84f98>),
 (<Element 'name' at 0x7f9c85a8f048>, <Element 'desc' at 0x7f9c85a8f098>),
 (<Element 'name' at 0x7f9c85a8f1d8>, <Element 'desc' at 0x7f9c85a8f228>)]
```

And finally:

```
>>> [(x.find('name').text, x.find('desc').text) for x in tree.findall('.//name/..')]
[('A00', 'Cholera'),
 ('A00.0', 'Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae'), 
 ('A00.1', 'Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor'), 
 ('A00.9', 'Cholera, unspecified')]
```